# Jenkins Email notification based on build step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins project configured with two different build step, and I need separate email to be triggered for each build step. Any suggestion please

Comment: What do you do in those 2 build steps? Do they generate any logs?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: You can send your mails in whatever part of the script per stage you want.

If you are using Pipeline plugin, your Groovy Script could be like this:

```
stage 'job-1 stage'
node('master') {
     try {
        //Run job-1 steps
     } catch(e) {
        String error = "${e}";
        // Make the string with job info, example:
        // ${env.JOB_NAME}
        // ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} 
        // ${env.BUILD_URL}
        // and other variables in the code
        mail bcc: '', body: "<b>${pivote}</b><br>\n\nMensaje de error: ${error}\n\n<br>Projecto: ${env.JOB_NAME} <br>Build Number: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} <br> URL de build: ${env.BUILD_URL}", cc: '', charset: 'UTF-8', from: '', mimeType: 'text/html', replyTo: '', subject: "ERROR CI: Project name -> ${env.JOB_NAME}", to: "${mails_to_notify}";
        error "${error}"
    }
}

stage 'job-2 stage'
node('master') {
     try {
        //Run job-2 steps
     } catch(e) {
        String error = "${e}";
        // Make the string with job info, example:
        // ${env.JOB_NAME}
        // ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} 
        // ${env.BUILD_URL}
        // and other variables in the code
        mail bcc: '', body: "<b>${pivote}</b><br>\n\nMensaje de error: ${error}\n\n<br>Projecto: ${env.JOB_NAME} <br>Build Number: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} <br> URL de build: ${env.BUILD_URL}", cc: '', charset: 'UTF-8', from: '', mimeType: 'text/html', replyTo: '', subject: "ERROR CI: Project name -> ${env.JOB_NAME}", to: "${mails_to_notify}";
        error "${error}"
    }
}
```